# How do I derive \$(i_x)/(V_A-V_B)\$ in this circuit?

Tags: differential, kirchhoffs-laws, formula-derivation

I have this circuit below:
http://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-a5380479d6b436dcfb9a36252ac3f1c1?convert_to_webp=true

Can I make the small signal equivalent circuit as shown below and when doing the KCL equation, When I pick the node above $$g_mV_A$$  can I simply assume $$g_m*V_A-g_m*V_B-2*i_x=0$$?

http://qph.is.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-20c87843bd57823b4c4489e360000033

Comment: I really appreciate the effort of drawing your schematic with paint (and a mouse apparently) but there is a built in schematic editor. If you could take the time to redraw your "I'm stuck here" drawing that will be great. +1 for a decent homework question (at last).

Answer (score 1):

Although your answer is almost right (except for the sign), I'm not sure your technique is. KCL doesn't directly yield \$g_mv_A-g_mv_B-2i_x=0\$. Further, \$v_A\$ and \$v_B\$ aren't base-emitter voltages as you've drawn, but are instead ground-referred.

Let's define a dummy voltage \$v_x\$, which is the voltage at the emitters. The pi model gives us \$i_{T_1}=g_m(v_A-v_x)\$, and \$i_{T_2}=g_m(v_B-v_x)\$. KCL at the emitter node forces \$i_{T_1}+i_{T_2}=0\$, thus \$g_m(v_A-v_x)+g_m(v_B-v_x)=0\$ and, therefore,
$$v_x=\frac{v_A+v_B}{2}$$
In other words, \$v_x\$ is the average of \$v_A\$ and \$v_B\$. Knowing that \$i_x\$ is defined to be \$i_{T_2}\$,
$$i_x=g_m(v_B-v_x)$$
$$i_x=g_m\left(v_B-\frac{v_A+v_B}{2}\right)$$
$$\therefore i_x=g_m\frac{v_B-v_A}{2}$$

---

Personally, I prefer using the [T (tee) model](http://m.eet.com/media/1200631/F1x600.jpg) for just about everything, and here's why.

If we define two "emitter resistors" strung between \$v_A\$ and \$v_B\$, each of value \$r_e=1/g_m\$ like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBey0i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

then we know that the current that flows from \$v_B\$ to \$v_A\$ is simply that of two series resistors of value \$r_e\$,
$$i_x=\frac{v_B-v_A}{2r_e}=g_m\frac{v_B-v_A}{2}$$
Notice that I snuck in a claim that the current flowing from \$v_B\$ to \$v_A\$ is \$i_x\$. This is because, in the T model, [virtually] all the current that flows through the emitter resistors \$r_e\$ is supplied by a current source connected to the transistors' collectors. Thus, the current flowing from \$v_B\$ to \$v_A\$ ***is*** \$i_x\$.

Notice that we can also see, by inspection, that \$v_x\$ is \$(v_A+v_B)/2\$. This is an added bonus of the T model.

Comment: Wouldn't that imply a different answer, see: \$i_x=g_m\frac{v_B-v_A}{2}\$ -> \$\frac{i_x}{v_B-v_A}=\frac{1}{2}g_m\$ -> \$\frac{-i_x}{v_A-v_B}=\frac{1}{2}g_m\$ ->  \$\frac{i_x}{v_A-v_B}=\frac{-1}{2}g_m\$

Comment: Apologies, you're right; my sign is different from yours. I've corrected the post accordingly. This means both your technique and your answer were wrong. You can confirm polarity by doing a quick sanity check: If you were to "wiggle" \$v_B\$ by increasing it, it would increase \$i_{T_2}\$, thus, \$i_x\$ increases. Therefore, \$i_x/(v_A-v_B)\$ should be negative.

Comment: Then, I don't understand why in my answer book they say \$\frac{i_x}{V_A-V_B} = 1/2*g_m\$   "ix increases. Therefore, ix/(vA−vB) should be negative" I don't see how a small increase in ix would lead to negative  ix/(vA−vB) if vA > vB

Comment: The answer book can easily be wrong; it's written by a human, and humans are notorious for forgetting minus signs. Returning to my quick sanity check, an increase in \$v_B\$ leads to an increase in \$i_x\$ as \$T_2\$ becomes more conductive and steals away current from \$T_1\$. Likewise, a decrease in \$v_A\$ also leads to an increase in \$i_x\$. Thus, when you define a quantity where \$v_B-v_A\$ is *negative*, i.e. \$v_A-v_B\$, then \$i_x\$ will *decrease* as the quantity increases, and therefore \$i_x/(v_A-v_B)\$ is negative.

Comment: Wait, I don't get this part: "when you define a quantity where vB−vA is negative i.e. vA−vB, " To have vB-vA as a negative value vA>vB, but in that case "vA−vB">0. "then ix will decrease as the quantity increases. " So, what does this mean? Does ix decrease, when  the 'quantity' 'vB−vA' increases, so when vB become larger and vA smaller?

Comment: That's right. When \$v_A>v_B\$, the quantity \$v_B-v_A\$ is negative and \$v_A-v_B\$ is positive. And under this circumstance, \$i_x\$ is negative. However, when \$v_B>v_A\$, then \$i_x\$ is positive.